# PHP Page not displaying

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I would like to use the following PHP page in a PHP template. From what I've read I  need to include the Post ID but I don't know how to do so. My code is below

```
    <?php

          $postid = get_the_ID();

            if( have_rows('repeat_field', $postid ) ) :
            $i = 0;

              // loop through the rows of data
                while ( have_rows('repeat_field', $postid ) ) : the_row();

                $i++;

                    // display a sub field value

              if (!empty(get_sub_field('feature_image_post', $postid ))) {

                  echo '<a href="';
                  the_sub_field('article_link', $postid); 
                  echo '">';
                    echo '<div class="post-feature" style="background-image:url(';
                    the_sub_field('feature_image_post', $postid); 
                    echo ')"';
                    echo 'region="';
                    the_sub_field('region');
                    echo '">';
              } 

                if( $i >= 200 )
                {
                  break;
                }


                endwhile;

            else :

                // no rows found

            endif;

            ?>
```

Comment: This should not be a new question. Outside of the context of your other question, your problem here will not be apparent.

Comment: @Milo I updated the question to get straight to the point. It cuts down on what was asked before. My question is different because I'm using  a different example of how I am defining $postid

Comment: But your problem in the other question is that you have two separate http requests. It's like opening two different browser windows and visiting two different pages- you wouldn't expect that one page in one window had access to the data in the page in the other window. If you make an http request from one page to another via javascript, any data you need to use in that target page has to be passed via javascript- in this case the post ID.

Comment: That definitely makes sense but is there an example on how to do that?

Comment: If you are simply trying to pull the ACF field data from the specific page that you are on (not the ACF field data from a different page), you don't need to include the page ID at all. Is the data coming from the same page, or a different one?

Comment: @ Ryan The data is coming from a different page. I'm making the call via AJAX

Comment: @Milo, @Ryan What I notice it that the template that that is pulling in the information contains `global $post;` `$category = $wp_query->get_queried_object();`